# linking ember-cli master causes merge errors

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I have followed the ember-cli instructions for referencing the master branch in development.

It works fine when I use a new ember project.

However when I try linking to an existing ember project i get this kind of error:

```
Merge error: file "bootstrap/.bower.json" exists in vendor and vendor - pass option { overwrite: true } to mergeTrees in order to have the latter file win
```

I have tried everything to get rid of this (i.e. clone repository, and initialize things one step at a time.

The occurs once I install stefanpenner/loader.js#1.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Fundamental problem is that vendor directory has changed to bower_components directory.
this leaves the .bowerrc file pointing to "vendor" which seems to cause the problem.

make sure to - delete .bowerrc file or update it so it points to bower-components

This will happen as long as you do everything in the right order

1. go to directory containing your working copy (master) of ember-cli
2. npm link
3. go to your code directory
4. npm link ember-cli
5. ember init (make sure to update .bowerrc, and update/merge .gitignore, bower.json, package.json)
6. you should be good to go

The problem I was having was running bower install BEFORE ember init (per the ember-cli web page)
This was installing stuff in the vendor directory, so you end up with duplicates.